# Warning: json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in plugins/system/kazaam/kazaam.php on line 602

Tags: php, joomla

I installed [KAZAAM](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/structure-a-navigation/menu-systems/menu-editors/20057) for my joomla to creat an [automated](http://www.yn47.com/m/3000004/b-b-king-how-blue-can-you-get-1994-emg-int.html) menu from category. It is showing error "Warning: json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in plugins/system/kazaam/kazaam.php on line 602".

```
line 602 "$params = (object) json_decode($this->getParam('params'));"
```

Comment: You should be decoding JSON not array, and question is not explanatory

Comment: The error is clear: you have to pass a string instead of an array. Do you know what  you want decode? Perform a `print_r($this->getParam('params'))` at line 601;

Comment: You have to edit your question showing your code and more detailed info. By a rapid search, I don't have evidence of a Kazaam bug like this, so I think that can depends of your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pass a string instead of an array. Do you know what you want decode? Try doing `print_r($this->getParam('params'))`.